# How to get a list of running programs in Lubuntu 14.04?

Tags: 14.04, lubuntu, process

Just like in Windows where you can see and maybe "kill" one of the running programs.

How to get such a list ?

Comment: try `ps aux` command.

Answer (score 8, accepted):

It is called "Task Manager" in Lubuntu.

[image]

If you want it from commandline: `top` and `htop`.

[From their wiki](http://wiki.lxde.org/en/LXTask):

> LXTask is the standard task manager and system monitor of LXDE. It starts via Ctrl+Alt+Del and is extremely lightweight.
>
> To remove an unresponsive application, you may use Term or Kill. It is recommended to first try Term, to see if the application can respond.

Answer (score 5):

Give a try to `ps aux` or `ps -ef` commands.

From `man ps`

```
To see every process on the system using standard syntax:
      ps -e
      ps -ef
      ps -eF
      ps -ely

To see every process on the system using BSD syntax:
      ps ax
      ps axu

To print a process tree:
      ps -ejH
      ps axjf

To get info about threads:
      ps -eLf
      ps axms

To get security info:
      ps -eo euser,ruser,suser,fuser,f,comm,label
      ps axZ
```

Answer (score 3):

Use "System Monitor" to view the running processes with GUI, if you don't want to use the "Terminal" typed commands.

[image]